# PYTHONPATH error Linux Terminal v Console

Tags: python, ubuntu, path, terminal, environment-variables

I am having trouble getting PYTHONPATH set. I have added this line to ~/.bashrc

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/sayth/My_Programs/Python
```

I ran `source ~/.bashrc`

Here is the issue though if I type python at the terminal and get a python REPL I can then import modules from ~/My_Programs/Python without a problem.

However if I run bpython or idle or a console in ninja-ide etc then import fails.

```
>>> import temperature
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import temperature
ImportError: No module named temperature
>>>
```

I can do sys.path.append(/home/sayth/My_Programs/Python) and get it working, but I wanted the PYTHONPATH to work in all consoles automatically. How?

PS using ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you did not launch your ninja-ide from the same terminal that you `source ~/.bashrc` from -- the new environment variable only influences child processes of whichever shell process did the sourcing. Of course, logging out and in again *may* do it, but if you're living entirely in the GUI (e.g., you click a button to start the ninja-ide), then you may need to go to some more effort to set your environment variable. How you do so depends upon which graphical environment you're using.

Comment: So there isn't a way to add a directory to pythonpath so that importing works for any python ide or shell?

Comment: If you add it to `/etc/environment` then it will be added to EVERY login that uses `pam_env(8)` PAM module -- perhaps more than you expected, but it would certainly get everything, even if your GUI environment doesn't make it easy for you to set environment variables yourself.